# I need to create an application that allows my users to work online and offline in CRUD operations in the same database, what solution can I apply?

Tags: angular, database, web-applications, offline

The idea is to create a web application that allows different users to manage a database from cell phones and computers, but sometimes these users, due to work locations, need to work without an Internet connection only from a computer. What would be the best solution?

Comment: This is not a specific question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.